# Map Object Model to XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I am working on a generation of PDF based on a ASP.Net MVC form, the datamodel that I am passing to the Controller is a complex object and I need to map it to XML and then generate a PDF from it.
The problem is that I don't know what is the best way to map the object to XML.
My code is in C# by the way.
I will appreciate any sugestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really bordering on overly broad, but here are some options that are built into .NET:

- Use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `System.Xml.Serialization`: Mark your class(es) as `[Serializable]`, use attributes to specify node names and mappings.  You could implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) on your class as well to further control and customize how the XML would be read or written.
- [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `System.Xml.Linq`: You may find this interface easier to use if you don't need to serialize the entire class, and/or your class structure has little resemblance to the XML structure you're looking to create and you don't want to/can't modify the class(es).  Just be aware that this will require updates if your classes change, whereas `XmlSerializer` will more easily incorporate changes to the class (unless you override `ReadXml` and `WriteXml`, in which case you're in the same boat).